# Stored Procedure for comparing rows and then performing further action

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My application allows the user to add or delete records at will . To delete records the user needs to only empty the field . Because of this constraint I have to delete all the records for the user in the particular tables and then insert (even if the records have not changed/only additions were made) .

I want to change this arrangement and set up a stored procedure which compares the data from the user with the one present in db and then perform insert/delete or update .

Can this be done ? I am not too well versed with Stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put...yes. 
[Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) allow you to perform multiple statements, which can simply resolve any of the problems you might need resolved. 
You can check out a tutorial [here.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/) 
 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I just went through a different tutorial . I am left with two questions : 

1) Can I pass an array variable as parameter to a stored procedure ?(otherwise I will have to call stored procedure multiple times for the array of results to update/delete) / 
2) I need to compare the user provided input(an array of items) with the values already present inside db and delete if user has not provided certain values (as compared to providing them earlier)

Comment: no; you cannot pass an array as a parameter; only the **accepted datatypes**